# How to launch gtalk from another app in android

Tags: android

I just want to know how to fire intent to launch google talk from my application.
Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Jeff Sharkey on this Google Groups thread may be helpful: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5687aed2f49b1789